# Rails path nomenclature not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I have a Fixer model, but, unlike all the other models in my app, its routing isn't working right, even though there's a resource line for it in the routes file.

The problem is, when I try to link to the basic show path any number of ways, like

```
<%= link_to "Fixer", fixer_path(@fixer) %>
```

or

```
<%= link_to "Fixer", @fixer %>
```

or

```
<%= link_to "Fixer", fixer_path(@fixer.id) %> # I got desperate
```

it links to /fixers.[:id] (not a real page) instead of /fixers/[:id]. No idea what's happening, cause my resources line is there, and show is a basic resources action, and all the other similarly resourced models seem to be working just fine.

Any ideas? (I can put more code up if necessary. Just not sure what would be relevant).

EDIT -- The Fixers output in my rake routes:

```
       fixers GET    /fixers(.:format)           fixers#index
              POST   /fixers(.:format)           fixers#create
    new_fixer GET    /fixers/new(.:format)       fixers#new
   edit_fixer GET    /fixers/:id/edit(.:format)  fixers#edit
              GET    /fixers/:id(.:format)       fixers#show
              PUT    /fixers/:id(.:format)       fixers#update
              DELETE /fixers/:id(.:format)       fixers#destroy
```

Whoa. Just noticed after posting this that the 5th line is missing the "fixer" before the show action line that all my other models have. Why would that have happened? How do I fix it?

EDIT -- I figured it out! Really dumb issue. For some reason, back when I was learning how to do all this, I both included a resources line and added this line above it:

```
match '/fixer', to: 'fixers#new'
```

When I took that line out (cause it was redundant), the problem went away. I guess I was messing with the Rails routing automagic. They really do make those defaults the best option.

Comment: Are you sure that there isn't a typo in your link_to? fixers_path(@fixer) would generate the url with a dot.

Comment: Please post your rake routes output.

Comment: Yup. Not a typo. (I've made that mistake before). As an added wrinkle, what I'm actually doing is calling the fixer through its associated user. I'm sure that relation is correct, though, as I've tested it elsewhere and in the console. So I'm doing, for instance, fixer_path(@user.fixer) or fixer_path(@user.fixer.id).

Comment: I went into the routes.rb file to post it and then saw the problem that I listed above. Solved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey I have had this same problem before.. and unfortunately have resorted to doing the following: `link_to "link text", "/fixers/#{@fixer.id}"` I would love to know the actual correct answer for this though.

Comment: My fix is above. Just figured out that I'd done something stupid, is all, so I doubt your issue has the same root cause.